# How to execute the following ES6 lines in sequence?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm using the following function to load high-res version of images once they have loaded:

```
store.loadFullPano = (pano) => {
  $('#panos-wrapper').addClass('blurred')
  setTimeout(function () {
    const image = new Image()
    image.src = pano.url
    image.onload = () => {
      pano.url = pano.urlHigh
      $('#panos-wrapper').removeClass('blurred')
    }
  }, 1000)
}
```

As you can see I'm blurring the low-res images with CSS. It works...except the low-res image shows for a few seconds after the hig-res one has been replaced and the blur has been removed.

I think that's because the two lines inside `image.onload` are being executed at the same time (or the last one first).

Is there a way to execute the first one and only *then* the last one?

**EDIT:**

I used a promise:

```
  var p = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    pano.url = pano.urlHigh
    console.log('1')
    resolve(pano.url)
  })
  p.then(function () {
    $('#panos-wrapper').removeClass('blurred')
    console.log('2')
  })
```

But the low-res is still showing for a few seconds. What's a possible solution for this?

Comment: what type of object is `pano`?

Comment: Promises would only be useful if Pano has a method to return a promise that resolves when it is finished loading. Making your own in this case won't help.

Comment: @BrettZamir `pano` is a plain object inside a JavaScript array.

Comment: If `urlHigh` has the high resolution image URL, how is it being detected then to set the high res image? Just assigning to an object shouldn't normally do that (unless `pano` is using `Object.observe`).

Comment: It seems to me you shouldn't be seeing any hi-res image here at all... Are you sure that you are seeing that?

Comment: @BrettZamir Oh, yeah I made a mistake. `pano` is a reactive object, meaning that if its value changes it's automatically rendered in the template.

Comment: Maybe the template engine behind `pano` then has a way of providing a promise or letting you supply a callback... What is the template engine?

Comment: @BrettZamir You're right, thanks. I'll go check the docs. This is the framework: https://vuejs.org/.

Comment: It appears the semi-colon key on your keyboard may be broken.

Comment: Don't you think the high-res image has to be loaded as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Vue docs](http://vuejs.org/guide/reactivity.html#Async_Update_Queue):

> you can use Vue.nextTick(callback) immediately after the data is changed. The callback will be called after the DOM has been updated

and

> There is also the vm.$nextTick() instance method, which is especially handy inside components, because it doesn’t need global Vue and its callback’s this context will be automatically bound to the current Vue instance

Depending on how it is implemented, however, I'm not sure that "the DOM has been updated" will be enough though, since loading an image may need more time. Maybe by then though, if you can obtain the updated/created hi-res image object though, maybe you can wait for its `onload`...

**Update:** It looks like you will need to utilize the API to obtain the image element and to use its `onload` listener since images do not load synchronously. Apparently you can get this with the [`$el` property](http://vuejs.org/api/#vm-_24el).

So I'd try updating to something like this:

```
image.onload = () => {
  pano.url = pano.urlHigh
  pano.$el.onload = function () {
      $('#panos-wrapper').removeClass('blurred')
  };
}
```

[v-el](http://vuejs.org/api/#v-el) might also be handy.

***Update 2:***

If `$el` doesn't find your image element, I'd try this:

```
<img v-bind:src="pano.url" v-el:image>
```

and then:

```
image.onload = () => {
  pano.url = pano.urlHigh
  pano.$els.image.onload = function () {
      $('#panos-wrapper').removeClass('blurred')
  };
}
```

Comment: Wow, you read fast. Unfortunately, it didn't work: `Vue.nextTick(function () {
        $('#panos-wrapper').removeClass('blurred')
      })` Maybe it's impossible.

Comment: How did you know to add `url`? Is that particular reactive object documented somewhere?

Comment: Or are you binding the `url` value to an image tag?

Comment: I created the `url` key: `pano: [
        {
          index: 0,
          type: 'livingRoom',
          url: require('../assets/pano-1-low.jpg'),` Vue.js automatically updates the template if any value changes.

Comment: Yes in this way: `v-bind:src="pano.url"`. More info: http://vuejs.org/guide/syntax.html

Comment: How about trying `pano.$el.onload`?

Comment: Doesn't work, ha. I think I'll just blur the low-res images in Photoshop.

Comment: See http://vuejs.org/api/#v-el ... it looks like that might help you be able to access the image element if `$el` isn't getting it.

Comment: Ok, made one last update... I guess `$el` might have been grabbing a parent element in your template or something--can't know without seeing it. But the approach I added really should do the trick, I'd think.

Answer (score 1):

The browser will be executing these lines in sequence. Add a breakpoint above the first line then just use the step-by-step debugger to follow the flow.

```
image.onload = () => {
  debugger;
  pano.url = pano.urlHigh
  $('#panos-wrapper').removeClass('blurred')
}
```

I suspect that they seem out of order because `pano.url = pano.urlHigh` probably doesn't have an immediate effect.

It's a synchronous statement and JavaScript is single threaded, which means that even if you've got some other code that responds to changing the url of `pano`, it can't execute until it's finished executing all the synchronous code.

```
pano.url = pano.urlHigh
// there's no time for any other code to happen elsewhere here.
$('#panos-wrapper').removeClass('blurred')
```

The jQuery call is guaranteed to be the next thing that happens after you set the url property.

If you're using a template engine that reacts to changes in the properties of `pano`, then the best way to run the jQuery call after the changes have been made, is to delay it til the next frame.

```
pano.url = pano.urlHigh
requestAnimationFrame(function() {
  $('#panos-wrapper').removeClass('blurred')
});
```

Comment: I see. So is there a way to execute `$('#panos-wrapper').removeClass('blurred')` only when `pano.url = pano.urlHigh` has finished?

Comment: What do you mean when you say 'finished'?

Comment: Only when `pano.url` has been set to `pano.urlHigh` (and that has been reflecting in the template)?

Comment: Okay, maybe that has more to do with the reative framework I'm using than with the posted code?

Comment: You should be able to make it work with requestAnimationFrame. Updated the end of my answer.

Comment: I did this: `pano.url = pano.urlHigh
      window.requestAnimationFrame(function () {
        $('#panos-wrapper').removeClass('blurred')
      })` And without `window`. The low-res image is still showing up without the blur for a few seconds.

Comment: In that case, it sounds like the only option is to use `setTimeout` to delay for a few seconds instead.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help. I'll do that (but isn't using `setTimeout` in cases like this a bit "hacky"? ha).

Comment: Definitely, but unless vue provides a mechanism for notifying you of when it's done rendering, I don't see another way.